# Ask for the MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

```
goods
id     name     rent_price
1     Toyota     400000
2     Honda      500000
3     Mazda      600000
4     Suzuki     700000
5     KIA        800000
```

.

```
customers
id     name
1     Ali
2     Budi
3     Candra
4     Doni
5     Eka
```

.

```
history_transactions
id    customer_id      date
1      1             2016-03-01 15:00:00
2      4             2016-03-02 15:00:00
3      4             2016-03-02 17:00:00
4      2             2016-03-03 09:00:00
5      4             2016-03-05 10:00:00
6      1             2016-04-06 10:00:00
7      5             2016-05-07 10:00:00
8      2             2016-06-08 10:00:00
9      1             2016-07-09 10:00:00
10     2             2016-08-10 10:00:00
```

.

```
history_rents
id    history_transaction_id         good_id
1                1                      1
2                2                      2
3                2                      5
4                3                      3
5                4                      1
6                4                      2
7                4                      3
8                4                      4
9                4                      5
10               5                      5
11               6                      3
12               7                      4
13               8                      3
14               9                      1
15               10                     1
```

I have lots of data
165.000 rows for history transaction
18.000 rows for customers

I need number days customers do transaction for  each customers

```
customers
id     name       day_trans
1     Ali            3
2     Budi           3
3     Candra         0
4     Doni           2 (history_transaction_id 2 & 3 count as 1)
5     Eka            1
```

And I need to count item rented for each customers

```
customers
id     name       rent_count
1     Ali            3
2     Budi           7
3     Candra         0
4     Doni           4
5     Eka            1
```

Please help for the query and what field should I make for the index

Comment: And what have you tried? Thank you

Comment: I use PHP with looping for each customers, and count for it.... but it takes very long time to get the data....

Comment: is it the best practice to get that data? or is there any query or script that can generate that data... :(

Comment: Give it some time Teddy. People will take a look

Comment: Do you want those two results through two different queries?

Answer (score 0):

**If you prefer the two outputs through two different queries:**

**Output #1:**

```
customers
id     name       day_trans
1     Ali            3
2     Budi           3
3     Candra         0
4     Doni           2 (history_transaction_id 2 & 3 count as 1)
5     Eka            1
```

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT 
C.id,
C.name,
COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(HT.`date`)) AS day_trans
FROM customers C
INNER JOIN history_transactions HT 
ON C.id = HT.customer_id
GROUP BY C.id 
ORDER BY C.id;
```

---

**Output #2:**

```
customers
id     name       rent_count
1     Ali            3
2     Budi           7
3     Candra         0
4     Doni           4
5     Eka            1
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT 
    C.id,
    C.name,
    COALESCE(t.total,0) AS rent_count
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    HT.customer_id,
    COUNT(*) total
    FROM history_rents HR 
    INNER JOIN history_transactions HT 
    ON HR.history_transaction_id = HT.id 
    GROUP BY HT.customer_id
) AS t
ON C.id = t.customer_id
ORDER BY C.id;
```

---

**And if you want to get them through one:**

```
SELECT 
    C.id,
    C.name,
    COALESCE(t.day_trans,0) AS day_trans
    COALESCE(t.total_rent,0) AS rent_count
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    HT.customer_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(HT.`date`)) AS day_trans,
    COUNT(*) total_rent
    FROM history_rents HR 
    INNER JOIN history_transactions HT 
    ON HR.history_transaction_id = HT.id 
    GROUP BY HT.customer_id
) AS t
ON C.id = t.customer_id
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you use a sub-query in your left join? It's going to break any indexes and slow it down a lot, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do them both in the same query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count(distinct date(ht.date)) as day_trans, count(*) as rent_count
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN history_transactions ht on c.id=ht.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN history_rents hr on ht.id=hr.history_transaction_id
GROUP by c.id
```